# Screeps - Where to find constants of Game Object?

Tags: javascript, screeps

Where can I find a list of the constants for the `Game` object like `Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS`, `Game.MOVE` and `Game.ATTACK`?

I cannot find it on http://screeps.com/docs/

Answer (score 5):

They can be found at [the game docs](https://screeps.com/docs/Game.php) (bottom of the page)

***Constants***

**Result Codes**

- `Game.OK`    0
- `Game.ERR_NOT_OWNER` -1
- `Game.ERR_NO_PATH`   -2
- `Game.ERR_NAME_EXISTS`   -3
- `Game.ERR_BUSY`  -4
- `Game.ERR_NOT_FOUND` -5
- `Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_ENERGY` -6
- `Game.ERR_INVALID_TARGET`    -7
- `Game.ERR_FULL`  -8
- `Game.ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE`  -9
- `Game.ERR_INVALID_ARGS`  -10
- `Game.ERR_TIRED` -11
- `Game.ERR_NO_BODYPART`   -12
- `Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_EXTENSIONS` -13

**Room.find() constants**

- `Game.CREEPS`    1
- `Game.MY_CREEPS` 2
- `Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS`    3
- `Game.SOURCES_ACTIVE`    4
- `Game.SOURCES`   5
- `Game.DROPPED_ENERGY`    6
- `Game.STRUCTURES`    7
- `Game.MY_STRUCTURES` 8
- `Game.HOSTILE_STRUCTURES`    9
- `Game.FLAGS` 10
- `Game.CONSTRUCTION_SITES`    11
- `Game.MY_SPAWNS` 12
- `Game.HOSTILE_SPAWNS`    13
- `Game.EXIT_TOP`  14
- `Game.EXIT_RIGHT`    15
- `Game.EXIT_BOTTOM`   16
- `Game.EXIT_LEFT` 17

**Directions**

- `Game.TOP`   1
- `Game.TOP_RIGHT` 2
- `Game.RIGHT` 3
- `Game.BOTTOM_RIGHT`  4
- `Game.BOTTOM`    5
- `Game.BOTTOM_LEFT`   6
- `Game.LEFT`  7
- `Game.TOP_LEFT`  8

**Body Parts**

- `Game.MOVE`  "move"
- `Game.WORK`  "work"
- `Game.CARRY` "carry"
- `Game.ATTACK`    "attack"
- `Game.RANGED_ATTACK` "ranged_attack"
- `Game.TOUGH` "tough"
- `Game.HEAL`  "heal"

**Structure Types**

- `Game.STRUCTURE_EXTENSION`   "extension"
- `Game.STRUCTURE_RAMPART` "rampart"
- `Game.STRUCTURE_ROAD`    "road"
- `Game.STRUCTURE_SPAWN`   "spawn"
- `Game.STRUCTURE_WALL`    "constructedWall"

**Colors**

- `Game.COLOR_RED` "red"
- `Game.COLOR_PURPLE`  "purple"
- `Game.COLOR_BLUE`    "blue"
- `Game.COLOR_CYAN`    "cyan"
- `Game.COLOR_GREEN`   "green"
- `Game.COLOR_YELLOW`  "yellow"
- `Game.COLOR_ORANGE`  "orange"
- `Game.COLOR_BROWN`   "brown"
- `Game.COLOR_GREY`    "grey"
- `Game.COLOR_WHITE`   "white"

**Room Modes**

- `Game.MODE_SIMULATION`   "simulation"
- `Game.MODE_SURVIVAL` "survival"
- `Game.MODE_WORLD`    "world"

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you're looking for:

1. [This](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php) is the list of constants used for finding stuff, expand `find(type, [opts])` (ex: `Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS`)
2. [This](http://screeps.com/docs/Spawn.php) is the list for game constants, expand `createCreep(body, [name], [memory])` (ex: `Game.ATTACK`)
3. [This](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php) is a list of option parameters for some functions, expand `findPath(fromPos, toPos, [opts])` (ex:`ignoreCreeps: boolean`)

This is what I was able to find, hope it helps! The documentation kinda hard to sort through!

Answer (score 0):

They are not bundled together in the docs.
They are described under the methods that use them.

The ones you asked for are at:

http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#find

http://screeps.com/docs/Spawn.php#createCreep